# Please help me apply my logo to this tennis ball! (I am so close, I know its something small and basic i'm missing)

Tags: texturing, uv, image, uv-image-editor

I unwrapped the ball, and placed the .png file in position in the uv editor.
Then, I added a material, and applied the uv map to the image texture as shown below:

[image: Screen sHot of blender file]

- it shows up in the material panel, but not on the ball!

Thanks,